# Tool to help in detecting all the pages in an ASP.Net application which are performing slowly

Tags: performance

Tool to help in detecting all the pages in an ASP.Net application which are performing slowly, without having to measure performance of each individual page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the server time, add time-taken to IIS logs (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944884) and then use an analysis tool e.g. R, to build histograms of the response time for each page.

If you want to track the actual load time in the users browser you'll need a Real User Monitoring (RUM) tool - basically gathers timing information from the Navigation Timing API and beacons it to a central server.